# Running Jar files from Python

Tags: java, python

I want to make a program that can execute jar files and print whatever the jar file is doing in my python program but without using the windows command line, I have searched all over the web but nothing is coming up with how to do this.

My program is a Minecraft server wrapper and I want it to run the `server.jar` file and instead of running it within the windows command prompt I want it to run inside the Python shell.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Daniel, what is the purpose of wanting to listen in on what other applications are doing?  Is it the logs you want to listen to or something else? Network traffic? Something else?  Please provide some more detail to paint a healthy picture of your problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: There is some more info now, Hope that helps explaining what Im doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you have to execute the program. A handy function for doing so:

```python
def run_command(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')
```

It will return an iterable with all the lines of output.
And you can access the lines and print using

```python
for output_line in run_command('java -jar jarfile.jar'):
    print(output_line)
```

add also `import subprocess`, as `run_command` uses [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: I get an error saying b'Error: Could not find or load main class craftbukkit.jar\r\n', so what do i do.

Comment: the output is originally from the jvm, so i suppose your java code has some bug.

Comment: well it is just a minecraft server jar file

Comment: oops, the command should be java -jar jarfile.jar, sorry. Correcting error now.

Comment: Ok now it is working but the java console is open so is there a wayto hide this?

Comment: what do you mean by java console? Do you mean that the python program is executing in a command prompt window?

Comment: No a command prompt looking window with the java logo on it comes up

Comment: That is all i can do, i don't know of any method to do what you want. Sorry :(
My suggestion is if you want to enter command too, run it directly from the command line.

Comment: @Daniel Alexander to write something to your subprocess yous should  stdin=subprocess.PIPE then `p.stdin.write("my command\n");p.stdin.flush()`

Comment: I had to add and extra shell=True feature to the subprocess.Popen statement in order to make it work for me. Don't what what the ups and downs of using a shell=True is, though!