# Running Fiji script in python

Tags: python, command, imagej

I am trying to get a home made Fiji script to sun inside Python by calling Fiji, but there's little documentation on how to do it. 
What I need is something like this:

```
    def myfijiscript:
        [CODE]
```

and then in Python:

```
    fiji(myfijiscript)
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: I guess you mean ``def myfijiscript():`` with parentheses. What's the problem with simply calling ``myfijiscript()`` (after importing what is needed of course) ?

Comment: I assume you checked http://fiji.sc/Scripting_toolbox#Python this link and it's not what you want, right? ;)

Comment: yeah, I did, and it's great for writing the script I want to use. Calling Fiji to run it from within Python, however, is where the problem is

Answer (score 3):

Python (or, to be precise, Jython) scripts within Fiji are executed using the [`org.python.util.PythonInterpreter`](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/index.html?org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html) class (see [source code](https://github.com/fiji/fiji-scripting/blob/master/src/main/java/common/ScriptRunner.java#L114-132)).

It doesn't make much sense to run a Jython script within a Java instance that is started from with Python, but have a look at [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257694/running-jar-files-from-python) questions concerning how to run external commands in python. You can save your script in a file `myscript.py` and then do:

```
call(["./ImageJ-linux64", "myscript.py"])
```

using the [ImageJ launcher](http://fiji.sc/Launcher) from the command line.

The other way is to use ImageJ as a library and just import the classes you need for your script, as others have suggested:

```
from ij import IJ
```